# Trilateration in 3-D Algorithm Returns NaN

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, jscience, trilateration

I tried to code the steps provided in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) article.

```
public static double[] localize(final double[] P1, final double[] P2, final double[] P3, final double[] P4, final double r1, final double r2, final double r3, final double r4)
{

    Point3d p1 = new Point3d(P1);
    Point3d p2 = new Point3d(P2);
    Point3d p3 = new Point3d(P3);
    Point3d p4 = new Point3d(P4);

    Vector3d ex = new Vector3d();

    ex.sub(p2,p1);
    ex.normalize();
    Vector3d p3p1 = new Vector3d();
    p3p1.sub(p3,p1);
    double i = ex.dot(p3p1);
    Vector3d iex = new Vector3d();
    iex.scale(i,ex);
    Vector3d ey = new Vector3d(p3p1);
    ey.sub(iex);
    ey.normalize();
    Vector3d ez = new Vector3d();
    ez.cross(ex, ey);
    double d = p2.distance(p1);
    if(d - r1 < r2)
        System.out.println("d - r1 < r2");
    if(r2 < d + r1)
        System.out.println("r2 < d+r1");
    double j = ey.dot(p3p1);

    double x = (Math.pow(r1,2) - Math.pow(r2,2) + Math.pow(d,2))/(2*d);
    Vector3d exx = new Vector3d();
    exx.scale(x, ex);
    double y = ((Math.pow(r1,2) - Math.pow(r3,2) + Math.pow(i,2) + Math.pow(j,2)) / ((2*j)) - ((i/j)*x));
    Vector3d eyy = new Vector3d();
    eyy.scale(y, ey);

    double z1 = Math.pow(r1,2) - Math.pow(x,2) - Math.pow(y,2);
    z1 = Math.sqrt(z1);
    double z2 = z1*-1;

    Vector3d ezz1 = new Vector3d();
    Vector3d ezz2 = new Vector3d();
    ezz1.scale(z1, ez);
    ezz2.scale(z2, ez);
    Point3d result1 = new Point3d();
    result1.add(p1);
    result1.add(exx);
    result1.add(eyy);
    result1.add(ezz1);

    Point3d result2 = new Point3d();
    result2.add(p1);
    result2.add(exx);
    result2.add(eyy);
    result2.add(ezz2);
    if((result1.distance(p4) - r4) <= (result2.distance(p4) - r4))
        return new double[]{round(result1.x), round(result1.y), round(result1.z)};
    else
        return new double[]{round(result2.x), round(result2.y), round(result2.z)};

}
```

After`z1` is always negative after `z1 = Math.pow(r1,2) - Math.pow(x,2) - Math.pow(y,2)` step. Hence, taking square root makes it `NaN`.
Is this possible? Maybe I'm choosing the wrong points to do localization.

Could you please tell me where I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative value for `z1` would indicate no real solution, e.g. the intersection of the first and second sphere falls entirely inside or outside of the the third sphere. If your test values do not include at least one set for which a real solution exists, `z1` will always be negative.

Comment: How can I check uf they intersect or not?

Comment: Plot the points with your favorite tool; e.g. [Grapher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher).

Comment: what I mean is, I want to check if they intersect or not before calculating z1. At which step shold I do it? Or is z1 the indicator?

Comment: Right, `z1` serves as a kind of [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant).